# php json parsing objects

Tags: php, json, parsing

I have a JSON file that I need to parse. I'm new to php and trying to figure out how to correctly parse the object. My question is: `How do I parse the objects of an object that have different names`

One object has the name `Thresh` the next object in the list has the name `Aatrox` the name of the top level object is `data`

This is what the JSON looks like. I can access the information if I know the name of the object `$champion = $jfo->data->Thresh;` but I don't want to have to type in all the names of the champions. Is there an easy way to obtain all the separate objects without knowing the names? `Maybe regex?`

```
"data": {
    "Thresh": {
        "id": 412,
        "key": "Thresh",
        "name": "Thresh",
        "title": "the Chain Warden",
        "image": {
            "full": "Thresh.png",
            "sprite": "champion3.png",
            "group": "champion",
            "x": 336,
            "y": 0,
            "w": 48,
            "h": 48
        },

 "Aatrox": {
        "id": 266,
        "key": "Aatrox",
        "name": "Aatrox",
        "title": "the Darkin Blade",
        "image": {
            "full": "Aatrox.png",
            "sprite": "champion0.png",
            "group": "champion",
            "x": 0,
            "y": 0,
            "w": 48,
            "h": 48
        },
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: You really should consider renaming your objects to something generic like "person" or "champion" instead of "Thresh" and "Aatrox". After all, those names are already in the objects.

Comment: the problem is that it comes to us like that. the names are predefined
@felipsmartins i'll try to re-word it so that it makes more sense.

Comment: no, you don't use regexes on the json. that's pointless. `json_decode()` to a native php data structure and then use normal array/object search methods on that.

Comment: Also, it does not seems a valid json structure.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely want to make your keys generic - your life will be easier if `data` contains an array instead of an object -

Comment: @felipsmartins the entire file is in JSON format. I took a snippet of it. I wish I could make it more generic. It is the way it comes to us unfortunately. Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to go through each champion, I'd recommend using a foreach loop in PHP. You can use it as such:

```
foreach($json->data as $champion)
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: You probably want to make it `as $champion => $data` - but, in this case, it doesn't really matter since in your example, `$champion['key'] achieves the same thing